# Sending e-mail from Azure Databricks

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-databricks

We have a requirement to send e-mails from Azure Databricks in case of some conditions. We do not want to use SMTP to send e-mails.

We were planning to use Logic Apps to send the mails. Is there any way we can call a Logic App to send an e-mail in case of the condition is met.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can use logic apps which has multiple connectors to send the mails which include Gmail, Outlook, etc . while if you are checking whether the condition is met you can use the `Condition` action of the `Control` connector.

[image]

### **UPDATED ANSWER**

One of the workarounds is that you can call logic apps from Databricks notebook using REST API. Consider below is my code in data bricks notebook.

```
import requests as req
import json

input_data = {'X': 1, 'Y': 2}
url = '<YOUR_LOGICAPP_POST_REQUEST>'
resp = req.post (url, data=json.dumps(input_data))
print(resp.text)
```

Below is the flow of my logic app

[image]

**RESULT:**

[image]

**REFERENCES:**

1. [Office 365 Outlook - MSFT Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/office365/)
2. [control workflow actions - MSFT Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-control-flow-conditional-statement)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but how can we call this from Azure Databricks notebook

Comment: @HillolSaha sure, you can call logic app from Azure databricks using REST API. Please check the sample from the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. But, unfortunately, Logic App is not a service that is allowed in the subscription. Is there any alternative to Logic App

Comment: @HillolSaha Since that was the primary ask, I provided the solution with Logic apps, Please do consider raising another question since the requirement is different from the primary ask. However, as an alternative, you can use Azure functions too with Twilio SendGrid https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/partners/microsoft-azure-2021#create-a-twilio-sendgrid-account